# Error in accessing Windows Forms Designer Editor - Requires license for the plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

As above stated, I'm unable editing from the Designer mode a particular form.

Message:

```
Instances of this error (1)  
 
1.   Show Call Stack  
 
at MapInfo.Licensing.MapInfoLicenseProvider.GetLicense(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions)
at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternalRecursive(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License& license, String& licenseKey)
at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.Validate(Type type, Object instance)
at MapInfo.Engine.Session.SessionInternal..ctor()
at MapInfo.Engine.Session.Create()
at MapInfo.Engine.Session.GetCurrent(Boolean bCreate)
at MapInfo.Windows.Controls.MapControl.InitMapControl(Map map)
at MapInfo.Windows.Controls.MapControl..ctor(Map map)
at MapInfo.Windows.Controls.MapControl..ctor()  

 
Help with this error  
 
Could not find an associated help topic for this error. Check Windows Forms Design-Time error list   
 

 
Forum posts about this error  
 
Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How would I be able to add that license and where ?

Any useful hints appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you can get a license from http://www.gemapping.com/Products/mapxtreme_2005.htm

Comment: I assume you didn't consulted the [dev guide](https://www.pitneybowes.com/content/dam/support/software/product-documentation/public/mapxtreme/v6-7-0/en-us/mapxtreme-v6-7-0-developer-guide.pdf) did you?

Comment: @stuartd 404 dead page

Comment: Thing is that the manual states the license should be put in the specific directory and I've already done that, before, and still I'm getting the same error message ???

Comment: Sorry, it actually states 403 - forbidden